# Creating Multiple Keys in array for plist

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I'm trying to enable image document types to an app using objc. I have root access to the `plist` I need to write to. Just wrapping my head around how many keys, dictionaries, & arrays needed to code this has been frustrating me for over an hour. I can't get it right.

If I'm correct I'll need to create a `NSMutableArray` in a `NSDictionary` in another `NSMutableArray`?

I'm using NSMutableDictionary to write to the plist as below:

```
NSMutableDictionary *data; 
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) { 
        data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path]; 
    } else {
        //no plist
    }
```

This is what I need to add to the plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
      <string>Images</string>
      <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
      <string>Alternate</string>
      <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
      <array>
          <string>public.image</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you trying to insert dict in array and then a array in dict ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PList is the file representation of NSMutableDictionary :

You can use the following :

```
  NSMutableDictionary *data;
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) {
        data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
    } else {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        NSDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        NSString *images = @"Images";
        [dict setValue:images forKey:@"CFBundleTypeName"];

        NSString *Alternate = @"Alternate";
        [dict setValue:images forKey:@"LSHandlerRank"];

        NSMutableArray *LSItemContentTypes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *publicImage = @"public.image";
        [LSItemContentTypes addObject:publicImage];

        [dict setValue:LSItemContentTypes forKey:@"LSItemContentTypes"];


        [data setObject:array forKey:@"CFBundleDocumentTypes"];

    }
```

Comment: Thanks alot but you were missing one thing. You forgot to add: [array addObject:dict]; before the last line. Again, thanks alot.

Comment: Ok...no prob..I want to give an idea only...enjoy